# Unable to get data from new collection on mongodb on node.js using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get data from a (newly created and after renaming the old one) collection using mongoose on mongodb & node.js. But the below find method always returns empty list. The same code worked well with the old db and collection. Any idea?

```
module.exports.find = function (schemaName, schema, callback) {
    var orm = mongoose.model(schemaName, schema);
    orm.find(function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            looger.error(err);
        } else {
            callback(data);
        }            
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Umid, that helped too. But the actual issue was with naming convesion for the collections. Caps, camel etc naming are not accepted... :(. I don't understand the reason though.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, you saved a lot of time for me, would have never thought about camelCase being issue

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly set collection name:

```
var orm = mongoose.model(schemaName, schema, collectionNewName);
```